# Angular 7 HttpInterceptor not working from library project

Tags: angular, shared-libraries, angular7

**Current Setup**
I am using Angular 7.1.0 with following structure - a root or parent app with three library projects as shown below:

```html
app (root)
 |- corelib (project)
 |- lib1 (project)
 |- lib2 (project)
```

- As shown `app` is the root angular project with library projects `corelib`, `lib1` and `lib2`.
- The corelib project contains all the common code and is included as a dependency to both lib1 and lib2 projects.
- The `app` has its own routing module to load components in lib1 and lib2 projects.
- Note that `corelib` project does not contain any routing. However it does contain the `HttpInterceptor` service.
- The `lib1` project does not require any routing currently and mainly used as a dashboard. It uses `corelib` as a dependency.
- The `lib2` project (uses `corelib` as a dependency) requires routing and lazy loads routes via `loadChildren()` as shown below (excerpt from `app-routing.module.ts`).

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'some/path1', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'some/path1', component: Lib1FirstComponent },
    { path: 'some/path1/path2', loadChildren: () => Lib2Module }
];
```

When I run my project the default `app.component` is loaded during start - loads the `Lib1FirstComponent` - it makes an http call to show some JSON data. It works fine - it calls the `HttpInterceptor` service in `corelib` and initializes the headers, params etc., and successfully completes the request.

**Issue:**
My issue is with the `lib2` project which does load the default component and it also makes an http request in ngOnInit() method - however it does not seem to access my `HttpInterceptor` service at all - I cannot debug my `HttpInterceptor` service in `corelib` for this project. However it seems the headers and params are sent properly and I can view path, params and output via `console.log` and find that the service call gets completed successfully. I am trying to implement a common overlay service to show the message loading... while my http calls are being loaded.
I do not understand why I cannot access my HttpInterceptor service via debug mode in my `lib2` project.
Can you please let me know what I am missing here?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I solved this issue by moving my `HttpInterceptor` service from my `corelib` project in to the root `app` project.